# Joomla menu item templates wil not change from default

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla-template

I have a problem that has a simple fix I am sure. I  set my default template in joomla, but when I set the other menu items to use a different template, it still uses the default value instead.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start answering your question is important to know wich version of Joomla you are using. And also, how are you changing those values.
Anyway if you go to templates configuration under extensions, and enter to a specific template you can change and asign template to specific menu items, the same way you display modules only on certain pages.
Regards

Comment: actually, found out it was a bug in one of the plugins I had used.